# Wrapping extension of WebElement object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have class like this:

```
class Node(WebElement):
    def __init__(self, parent, id_):
        super().__init__(parent, id_)
   ...
   <some methods, and selectors in it>
```

and I have in test:

```
nodes = [node for node in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(node_xpath)]
```

Of course, `nodes` is a list of WebElements.

I want to cast it (wrap it) to be a list of `Node` type, so I can simply use its goodies, and have the power of the `WebElement` object as well.

But I cannot figure it out.

EDIT:

Well, sometimes sleep does the trick (i think):
Please look at this and give me feedback:

```
class Node(WebElement):
# I've got rid of arg `id_`, because the parent arg has it.
# I can only assume, that somewhere in lib, the parent arg has no `id_`  yet,
# and that is injected by argument... that is my guess
def __init__(self, parent):
    id_ = parent.id
    super().__init__(parent, id_)
```

...
<some methods, and selectors in it>

Why then WebElement itself doesn't look like this?:

```
class WebElement(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, id_=None, w3c=False):
    self._parent = parent
    self._id = id_ if id else parent.id
    self._w3c = w3c
```

... no idea. That would simplify my life a lot :)

Well, with `Node` set like above, this looks to do the trick (i am still in the middle of checking)

```
nodes = [Node(node) for node in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(node_xpath)]
```

Well, the `parent` argument name seems now a bit confusing, since it should be the same level, but I think I can live with that.

EDIT:

Nope, dead end...

```
    nodes[0].is_online()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/pods_and_nodes_page.py", line 130, in is_online
    for alarm in self.find_elements_by_xpath(self.alarms_xpath):
    File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 381, in find_elements_by_xpath
return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 684, in find_elements
return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENTS,
    File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    File "/lib/web/common/webelement.py", line 252, in __getattribute__
return WebdriverInterceptor().func_interceptor(self, MyWebElement, attr)
    File "/lib/util/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 550, in func_interceptor
func = super(webdriver_class, webdriver).__getattribute__(attr)
      AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

...or maybe not? It looks like someone in my project modified lib... Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing somethign like this. Note: this has not been tested.

```py
 @classmethod
 def from_WebElement(cls, a: WebElement):
    # Create new b_obj
    b_obj = cls()
    # Copy all values of A to B
    # It does not have any problem since they have common template
    for key, value in a.__dict__.items():
        b_obj.__dict__[key] = value
    return b_obj

nodes = [Node.from_WebElement(a=node) for node in self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(node_xpath)]
```

Code Ref from [here](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/191585)

Comment: Byt that's a class method. What I need, is a whole class.